# Range.FitTextWidth Always Returns Zero

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am programming a plug-in for word with c#. I need to get the width covered by a selection/range. The only property I noticed that gives this is the `Range.FitTextWidth` property but this always returns 0. What is the correct way of using `Range.FitTextWidth` or what are the alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43742324/11683?

Comment: Thanks @Gserg. This solves my problem.